# SqlConnection works with "Integrated Security =True" but I cannot connect with my login details

Tags: c#, sql-server, authentication, sqlconnection

I have some working code that is currently sitting on our test dev server that connects to an SQL server using Integrated Security/Trusted_Connection at the moment.

I will need to deploy this to a clients server and it will be scheduled to run every hour regardless of if a user is logged on or not.

as the user may not be logged in I assume that the Integrated security will not work.

The credentials I am putting in are the same as those I use to connect to the dev server. I have tried both with the domain "organisation\username" however this does not work either.

```
 SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("User id=username;" + "Password=xxxxxx; + "Data Source=datasrc;" + "Initial Catalog=catalog; " + "connection timeout=30");

myConnection.Open();
```

The above code does not work and results in the program 'hanging' before running `myConnection.Open()`

However putting "`Integrated Security=True;`" and removing the "User id" and "Password" sections of the string works.

When I try to use `"User id=name;" + "Password=xxxxxx;"` it does not work and just hangs.

Below is an error message from trying to login with username and password (windows authentication works fine) on the SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

The network path was not found"

Answer (score 1):

`Integrated Security=True;` means that the current credential being used to run the application pool will also be used to login to the SQL database. It doesn't make sense to use `Integrated Security=True;` *and* a User ID + Password. One or the other.

So, if your IIS instance is using an application pool logged in by `User123`, and the .NET application sitting on that IIS instance connects to a SQL database, then that .NET application will attempt to login to the SQL database using `User123`, so long as `Integrated Security=True;`. Typically people do this to ensure no plaintext passwords are present in the web.config, for security reasons. *EDIT*: you can see which user the application pool is using by right clicking the application pool in IIS manager and going to 'Advanced Settings'.

If it only works when you have `Integrated Security=True;` then that means only that user has permissions to access the SQL database. I would open up SSMS, navigate to the SQL database, and review the `Logins` under the `Security` navigation tree. Keep in mind there is a `Login` for the database server, as well as for the database itself, so you may have to configure this in two places.

Comment: Hi Omar, I am not trying to use both. at the moment the Integrated security is working. however when I deploy it to a server the program will be running even when user is not logged on, so I need to put in user credentials. I have checked and the username appears in the login section under security.

Comment: Is there a better practice of storing the passwords in the code without using integrated security

Comment: Well, inlining the username and password in your actual source code is never recommended. Regardless of if you're using Integrated Security or not, you should be storing that connection string in your `web.config` file (or if you're not making a web application, perhaps an `app.config` file). You can then retrieve that connection string using the `ConfigurationManager` class. Apparently you can also encrypt this configuration file, as detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files)